# Get all the resources of organization

Tags: amazon-web-services

My organization having 50+ users in aws and all are using s3, ec2 like all the other services now I want to list down all their resources and keep it updated so, is there any way to get all the resources created by any user I can scrap.

I have tried api and searching for comamands but no luck.

Comment: Maybe show what you have tried and explain why it didnt work, also maybe give an example of what you want to see. Are you expecting to see which user created which resource? or you just want a list of all resources? are you using multiple accounts with AWS organisations or control tower? have you tried using the cloudtrail logs?